# Editing arguments object inside of a JS class

Tags: javascript, class, methods, parameters, arguments

Given the following code:

```js
class ExampleClass {
  someMethod(x) {
    arguments[0] = 100;
    console.log(arguments[0]);
    return x;
  }
}
let example = new ExampleClass();
console.log([example.someMethod("5")]);

function someFunction(x) {
  arguments[0] = 100;
  console.log(arguments[0]);
  return x;
}
console.log([someFunction("5")]);
```

I would expect the output to be:

```
100
[100]
100
[100]
```

However in the class example this doesn't seem to work and instead it changes `arguments[0]` to 100 like it should but x remains unchanged.
So instead the output is:

```
100
["5"]
100
[100]
```

Is there some kind of workaround or will `arguments` never affect the parameters inside a class method?

Comment: Never try to "edit arguments", why would you do that? Assign `x = 100` if that is what you want.

Comment: The `arguments` object affecting the parameters (and vice versa) is generally regarded as a bad, confusing feature of legacy javascript, you shouldn't rely on that for anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the MDN documentation on [`arguments`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/arguments)

> In strict-mode code, the `arguments` object behaves the same whether or not a function is passed rest, default, or destructured parameters. That is, assigning new values to variables in the body of the function will not affect the `arguments` object. Nor will assigning new variables to the `arguments` object affect the value of variables.

And from the documentation of [strict mode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Strict_mode):

> All parts of ECMAScript classes are strict mode code, including both class declarations and class expressions — and so also including all parts of class bodies.

So the assignment to `arguments[0]` has no effect on the `x` parameter because this is in a class, which is in strict mode.

`arguments` is generally considered an obsolete feature in EcmaScript 6. This was traditionally used to implement rest and default parameters, which now have explicit syntax in parameter lists. Since class definitions are ES6, you should use the more modern syntax with them.